# iText Generate PDF with landscape and portrait pages

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem with a generation of PDF document. 
For example I need to generate 3 pages:

- First page (PORTRAIT) with portrait text
- Second page (LANDSCAPE) with portrait text
- Third page (PORTRAIT) with portrait text

I set after creating the first page:

```
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
```

and It seems to be working.
When I create the third page I set this code for the second time but the document is still in landscape mode.
This is my code:

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    document.open();
    document.newPage();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello 1"));

    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    document.newPage();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello 2"));

    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    document.newPage();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello 3"));

    document.close();
```

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: could you post more of the code

Comment: For iText7 have a look [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/page-orientation-and-rotation)

Comment: You set `PageSize.A4.rotate()` as page size both for page 2 and page 3. Thus, those two pages both are landscape. If you don't want the third page in landscape, don't set its size to landscape.

Comment: @mkl Ok. I removed `PageSize.A4.rotate()` but the third page is still in landscape mode

Comment: Not *remove* but *replace* by `PageSize.A4` without `rotate()`.

Comment: Ok. I'll make that an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `PageSize.A4.rotate()` as page size both right before creating page 2 and page 3 respectively. Thus, those two pages both are landscape.

As the most recently set `document` page size value is used for creating a new page, the result is the same if you don't set it at all before creating page 3, only before creating page 2.

If you don't want the third page in landscape, therefore, you explicitly have to set the page size value back to the portrait value `PageSize.A4` before creating page 3:

```
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
document.newPage();
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello 3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConverterProperties converterProperties=new ConverterProperties();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(out);  //here out is the object of ByteArrayOutputStream
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdf.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(1000,1500));
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(stringBuilder.toString(),pdf,converterProperties);
```